# The probability that of 5 points, 2 are outside the small circle and 3 outside it

Tags: probability

Suppose that a square with edge of length $a$ is inscribed inside a circle(the big circle) and then another circle(the small circle) is inscribed inside the square. What is the probability that from 5 randomly points chosen inside the big circle, two of them are outside the small circle and the other three are inside the small circle? 
Figuratively it would look something like this: [image]

The idea that I have is this:
First we find what is the probability that a point chosen randomly inside the big circle, is inside the small one(Lets denote this probability with $p1$). Then we find what is the probability that a point chosen randomly inside the big circle, is outside the small one(Lets denote this probability with $p2$).
Then the probability that the first point is outside the small circle, the second point is outside the circle and the third, fourth and fifth are inside the small circle is $p2*p2*p1*p1*p1$. Because the number of combinations of choosing two points outside the small circle(and the other three inside the small circle) is a 2-combination of 5 elements, the final result is:
$(2-combination  of 5 elements)*(p2*p2*p1*p1*p1)$.

I don't know whether this idea is correct or not.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Please indicate what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive responses appropriate to your skill level.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig   I made some indications of what I have attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should use geometry to determine the ratio of the radii of the two circles.  From the radii, you can compute the fraction of the area of the large circle occupied by the small circle.  That is the probability a randomly chosen point from the large circle is also inside the small circle, which you call $p1$.  You should note that $p2=1-p1$.  Now you have a binomial distribution of how many point out of five are inside the small circle.  Do you know how to compute that?

Comment: I know how to do the first part, but I haven't heard of binomial distribution.

Comment: The [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) gives you the probability of a certain number of successes out of a number of trials given that each trial is either a success or a failure, like flipping a (potentially biased) coin.  That is what you have.  If $p1=\frac 12$ could you compute the chance of two heads out of five tosses of a fair coin?

Comment: It should be I guess (2-combination of 5 elements)*((1/2)^5)

Comment: That is right.  The $(\frac 12)^5$ now becomes $p1^2(1-p1)^3$ because you need two successes and three failures